# Why session is not created in Bot-Bot?

Tags: automated-testing, android, mobile

I'm using [Bot-Bot](http://imaginea.github.com/bot-bot/), Android automation testing tool with record and replay features.

I was able to start a server, record and play sample [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) accompanied by a bot.

Now I need to test *my own* APK, so I did the following:

1. Put the `MyAndroid.apk` in the root folder
2. Added the following to default properties

   ```
   APP_PACKAGE= com.mkyong.android   
   DEFAULT_ACTIVITY=GridViewActivity
   FRAMEWORK=robotium

   TESTCASE_FOLDER=MyAndroidApp
   TEST_APK_FILENAME=MyAndroidApp.apk
   ANDROID_VERSION=android-16

   key.store=C:/Users/pramod.kumar/.android/debug.keystore
   key.store.password=android
   key.alias=androiddebugkey
   key.alias.password=android
   ```
3. Executed ant recorder command.
4. Did some actions.

After all that, I found that no session is being built on the server.

Comment: Pramod, I know it's been a while, but did you ever solve this problem? If you did, could you post a small answer? If you didn't (or you can't post a reasonable answer) do you feel the question remains useful?

Comment: @corsiKa ,No i was not able to get solution for this Still hope some one may have a solution.